# how to terminate strange services using a port causing error EADDRINUSE

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, server, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to install and configure nginx to execute php files, i installed php and everything went well and working except now my node app gives me `EADDRINUSE port: 443` error saying the port for my node server that I was using before is now busy.

I tried to log the services (i guess these are services) that are using the port `443` with `lsof -i tcp:443` and this is the result:
[image]
I tried to kill them with `kill -9 PID` but then they just come back, if i reload the site they become more.

so my question is what these actually are and how can i stop this madness?

my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name 45.76.***.10;
    root   /srv/main/site;
    index  index.html index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mysite.com.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/origin-pull-ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    autoindex off;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
    }


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kill the running task using the below commands -

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:443)
```

You can also use -

```
sudo fuser -k 443/tcp
```

Hope this helps.